# xrandr: can't add new mode with Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, xrandr

I'm in the same situation as the question "[xrandr: Can't add new mode…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18058/xrandr-cant-add-new-mode)", I can't add a new mode because xrandr does not support Nvidia binary driver (blame Nvidia yeah I know) but nvidia-settings can only detect resolutions up to 1024x768 when I try to use LG E2250 which support resolutions up to 1920x1080..

How can I add a new mode to Nvidia without using xrandr ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

You can try disper with option -r

disper: [disper on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/disper)

See `disper -h`

It's a command line tool focused on NVIDIA-drivers, because they don't support xrandr.

Comment: I already use xrandr and it doesn't work for the same reason, it doesn't see the supported resolutions higher than 1024x768, I'm stuck and forced to use an old PC just because it has an ATI video card :(